# Quarkus REST API with Multi<String> and APPLICATION_JSON return type adds additional wrapper to response

Tags: java, json, quarkus, mutiny, smallrye

I am trying to provide a JSON response from a Quarkus-based Rest API and I see that even if I provide a response with proper JSON, I get an additional array wrapper in my response. Is there a way to prevent the addition of array wrappers around the JSON?

The following is the Quarkus Rest API for GET requests:

```
  @Path("/testData")
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Multi <String> test() throws IOException {
      return Multi.createFrom().items(IOUtils.toString(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/TestJSON.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }
```

The following is my TestJSON.json file content:

```
{
  "isA": "customerDocument",
  "createdOn": "2022-10-10T12:29:43",
  "customerBody": {
    "customerList": [
      {
        "name": "Batman",
        "age": 45,
        "city": "gotham"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I compile the programme and obtain the response via Swagger-UI, then I get the response something like this:

```
[
  {
    "isA": "customerDocument",
    "createdOn": "2022-10-10T12:29:43",
    "customerBody": {
      "customerList": [
        {
          "name": "Batman",
          "age": 45,
          "city": "gotham"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

As we can see, an additional outer wrapper gets added to the response, which I did not provide. Can someone please let me know what's wrong here and provide some suggestions to avoid the addition of the wrapper array?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over the exact same issue that you had. The solution I found was to annotate the method with

```
@Stream(Stream.MODE.RAW)
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/6.2.0.Beta1/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e2799):

> **@Stream(Stream.MODE.RAW):** In this case each value is written directly to the wire, without any formatting, as it becomes available. This is most useful for values that can be cut in pieces, such as strings, bytes, buffers, etc., and then re-concatenated on the client side.

That page also explains the undesired behaviour that you and I encountered:

> **No @Stream annotation on the resource method:** Resteasy will collect every value until the stream is complete, then wrap them into a java.util.List entity and send to the client.

So, if I understand the above correctly, not only does the annotation change the formatting of the response, but also the "reactivity", i. e. whether to wait until the entire `Multi` has finished producing values and then sending them in bulk, or send it item-by-item, which might be another important consideration.